# How to insert values of one table into another

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables user and friends where users from user table can become friends.I have inserted 3 users into user table,now i want to make friends out of for example user_id = 1 and user_id = 2 but i don't know how to add this two id's in friends table.Photos of these two tables are attached.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `insert into friends (from_user, from_friend) values (1,2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... I don't really know what software you are using, but what you need is to declared a foreign key "UserId" column in your friend's table. Once that is done you can insert data in anyway possible by either using Mysql or a simple SQL insert:

```
INSERT INTO `friend`(UserId) VALUES (1)
```

Comment: I am using MySql Workbench both of these from_user and from_friend are actually foreign keys they reference on user_id which is primary key of the user table.For me the problem really is i don't know how to insert user_id value into these two columns in friends table.So for example it would be  a pair from_user = 1 from_friend = 2

Comment: ... Sorry, but your question was a little confusing. Lets see if I can get it right.  You have two tables "friends" and "user'. you are trying to insert the UserId of two users into "Friends". If this is the case you should have the option to manually create a query where you could do something like this:    `INSERT INTO friends (from_friend,from_user) VALUES (1,2)`